# Does CT act as a constant current source for a specific primary current?

Tags: transformer, current-measurement, multimeter, current-source, instrumentation-amplifier

I connected several resistors (1, 10, 100, 560 Ω) at the output of a 1000:1 CT (0-100 A measurement). I saw that the secondary current doesn't change for different resistors for a constant primary current. If the current is constant, then I<sup>2</sup>R will be very low for a tiny sampling resistor.

Is it good to use a tiny (say 1 Ω) sampling resistor? Or I am getting the whole concept wrong?

Comment: Example of low cost CT ... Burden resistor specified 10 Ohm ...  https://www.ubuy.co.id/en/product/37HXJQQ-jansane-sct-013-000-100a-non-invasive-ac-current-sensor-split-core-clamp-current-transformer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Is it good to use a tiny (say 1 ohm) sampling resistor?*

Firstly, proper names; it's a burden resistor and not a sampling resistor. So...

It's best to use the lowest value burden resistor you can because it does improve the accuracy of the CT over its full range of input currents. In effect the burden resistor can be referred to the primary and "placed" in parallel with the fat input wire. That fat input wire might have 10 μH inductance as it passes through the core and, at 50 Hz, that's an impedance of 3.14 mΩ.

Not much you might think and, damn right it shouldn't be much. But, the referred burden resistor of 1 Ω becomes 1000² times smaller (turns ratio squared) at 1 μΩ on the primary and, this takes the vast majority of the current that flows through the cable (rather than letting it flow through the 10 μH magnetization inductance of the cable).

If your burden resistor was 560 Ω, the referred resistance on the input winding would now be 0.56 mΩ and, as you can possibly see, the vast majority of the input current does not now flow in that referred resistor hence, you start to get errors AND you start to cause core saturation problems.

> *Does CT act as a constant current source for a specific primary
> current?*

It does in the main; that's what it's supposed to do but, don't make the burden resistor too high.

Comment: Still confused about the power consumption issue. For 1 amp secondary current 10 ohms burden will cause 10 watts power dissipation, and for 100 ohms, it will be 100 watts. Can you clarify this issue?

Comment: Sure, if the secondary is 1 amp then those powers are correct so, use a 1 ohm burden and get a dissipation of 1 watt. Of course the CT||Burden output voltage will be lower but, amplifiers are cheap and accurate these days @SadatRafi